# Vue2 | DIV not changing height on v-for

Tags: css, vue.js

I got a div like:

```
<div class="pt-4">
  <h5>Genres:</h5>
  <div class="inline-block float-left" v-for="(genre, index) in moreData.genres" :key="index">
    <span v-if="index < moreData.genres.length-1" class="mr-2">{{ genre.name }},</span>
    <span v-else>{{ genre.name }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when the content of the v-for statement gets rendered the height of the div stays the same. This is causing the next element overlapping (or at least floating) over it. I helped myself by setting "clear: both" but it's not a nice solution imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I solved it by setting "display: flex". This seems to be reactive to content changes and adjusting the dimensions of the DIV properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what is exactly your problem but if i understood well
You should give a go at flex

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="pt-4">
  <h5>Genres:</h5>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="genre">
      <span class="mr-2">Name,</span>
    </div>
      <div class="genre">
      <span class="mr-2">Name,</span>
    </div>
      <div class="genre">
      <span class="mr-2">Name</span>
    </div>
  </div
</div>
```

Comment: Yea, did that as I mentioned. But do you know why it's not working without flex? Why aren't the divs changing the height even if it's on `height: auto` by default?

Comment: A floating element is one where the computed value of float is not none.

As `float` implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed value of the display values, in some cases

cf: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float